# use select as column where id is equals to row id SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to query something like this.

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_ID, 
    (SELECT COUNT() WHERE ID = the current row COLUMN_ID WHERE status = 1) as column2, 
    (SELECT COUNT() WHERE ID = the current row COLUMN_ID WHERE status = 2) as column 3
```

How is it possible to make the select count used as a column, dynamic depending on the value of COLUMN_ID in each row

Sample data to query:

```
|      Column id      |       status     |
+---------------------+------------------+
|        0001         |         1        |
|        0001         |         2        |
|        0001         |         1        |
|        0002         |         1        |
```

Sample output

```
|      Column id      |     status 1     |     status 2     |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        0001         |         2        |        1         |
|        0002         |         1        |        0         |
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably possible. Please show us sample data and expected output so we can come up with a relevant answer.

Comment: Can a `COLUMN_ID` value appear multiple times in the table or is it unique?

Comment: @Shawn it is unique

Comment: But `ID` in one row can equal the `COLUMN_ID` of a different row and it might have duplicates? Or is `ID` in a different table?

Comment: @Shawn i updated the question

Comment: Your sample table doesn't have an id column, just column id and status... And the column id isn't unique like you said...

Comment: The answer below is all what you need

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUM with a CASE WHEN clause

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as column2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as column3
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941055/1/0)

*Another method*

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COLUMN_ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN_ID) as column2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN_ID) as column3
FROM TABLE
```

- [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/941055/5/0)

Comment: basically i want to select all id then for each id the column row will query where id = rowid

Comment: Have you tried that query?? The GROUP BY Clause will do this. AND the SUM + CASE WHEN will do the same thing as COUNT with condition

Comment: nope. because my queston is on how to do WHERE id = current row id. so for every id, the column value is the count for the status, where id =  current row id.

Comment: another explanation if my explanation is not good enough. basically i want,

Comment: for each id select count from table where status = 1 where id is equals to id[i]

Comment: @kev_m can you provide a sample data with expected output. your question is unclear

Comment: @kev_m the group by clause will show each COLUMN_ID + count of status=1 rows, count of status=2 rows for this COLUMN_ID

Comment: @kev_m then you are looking for the same query i provided.

Comment: @kev_m i provided another method check the answer update

Comment: @kev_m i provided an SQLFiddle link for each query check it out

Comment: Given the sample data, this looks like the correct answer to me!